# How to set a PlacementTarget for a WPF tooltip without messing up the DataContext?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a typical MVVM setup of Listbox and vm + DataTemplate and item vm's. The data templates have tooltips, which have elements bound to the item vm's. All works great.

Now, I'd like to have the tooltip placed relative to the listbox itself. It's fairly large and gets in the way when casually mousing over the listbox. So I figured I'd do something like this in the DataTemplate:

```
<Grid ...>
    <TextBlock x:Name="ObjectText"
        ToolTipService.Placement="Left"
        ToolTip="{StaticResource ItemToolTip}"
        ToolTipService.PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}">
    </TextBlock>
...
```

...with the static resource...

```
<ToolTip x:Key="ItemToolTip">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName.Name}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Details}" FontStyle="Italic"/>
        ...
    </StackPanel>
</ToolTip>
```

Here's my problem. When I use that PlacementTarget I get a binding error that the DisplayName.Name and Details are not binding. The object it's trying to bind to is not the item vm but the overall Listbox vm.

So my question is: how can I set the ToolTipService.PlacementTarget for a tooltip yet keep the DataContext inherited from its owner?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, a friend at work mostly figured it out for me. This way is super clean, doesn't feel hacky.

Here's the basic problem: as user164184 mentioned, tooltips are popups and therefore not part of the visual tree. So there's some magic that WPF does. The DataContext for the popup comes from the PlacementTarget, which is how the bindings work most of the time, despite the popup not being part of the tree. But when you change the PlacementTarget this overrides the default, and now the DataContext is coming from the new PlacementTarget, whatever it may be.

Totally not intuitive. It would be nice if MSDN had, instead of spending hours building all those pretty graphs of where the different tooltips appear, said one sentence about what happens with the DataContext.

Anyway, on to the SOLUTION! As with all fun WPF tricks, attached properties come to the rescue. We're going to add two attached properties so we can directly set the DataContext of the tooltip when it's generated.

```
public static class BindableToolTip
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToolTipProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "ToolTip", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(BindableToolTip), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnToolTipChanged));

    public static void SetToolTip(DependencyObject element, FrameworkElement value) { element.SetValue(ToolTipProperty, value); }
    public static FrameworkElement GetToolTip(DependencyObject element) { return (FrameworkElement)element.GetValue(ToolTipProperty); }

    static void OnToolTipChanged(DependencyObject element, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ToolTipService.SetToolTip(element, e.NewValue);

        if (e.NewValue != null)
        {
            ((ToolTip)e.NewValue).DataContext = GetDataContext(element);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataContextProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "DataContext", typeof(object), typeof(BindableToolTip), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnDataContextChanged));

    public static void SetDataContext(DependencyObject element, object value) { element.SetValue(DataContextProperty, value); }
    public static object GetDataContext(DependencyObject element) { return element.GetValue(DataContextProperty); }

    static void OnDataContextChanged(DependencyObject element, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var toolTip = GetToolTip(element);
        if (toolTip != null)
        {
            toolTip.DataContext = e.NewValue;
        }
    }
}
```

And then in the XAML:

```
<Grid ...>
    <TextBlock x:Name="ObjectText"
        ToolTipService.Placement="Left"
        ToolTipService.PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
        mystuff:BindableToolTip.DataContext="{Binding}">
        <mystuff:BindableToolTip.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName.Name}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Details}" FontStyle="Italic"/>
                    ...
                </StackPanel>
            </ToolTip>
        </mystuff:BindableToolTip.ToolTip>
    </TextBlock>
...
```

Just switch the `ToolTip` over to `BindableToolTip.ToolTip` instead, then add a new `BindableToolTip.DataContext` that points at whatever you want. I'm just setting it to the current DataContext, so it ends up inheriting the viewmodel bound to the DataTemplate.

Note that I embedded the ToolTip instead of using a StaticResource. That was a bug in my original question. Obviously has to be generated unique per item. Another option would be to use a ControlTemplate Style trigger thingy.

One improvement could be to have BindableToolTip.DataContext register for notifications on the ToolTip changing, then I could get rid of BindableToolTip.ToolTip. A task for another day!

Comment: Brilliant.  Thank you!  I agree that the docs in this area are crap.

Comment: I dug through all of the .NET Framework source code trying to understand ContextMenus and ToolTips.  Both are Popups.  Nice answer.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but it says that "BindableTooltip must derive from DependencyObject". But it can't inherit DependencyObject since it's a static class. I'm in VB.net, maybe it's because of that?

Answer (score 5):

ToolTips are not part of the visual tree as they are popup based. So your placement target biding (which uses Visual Tree search) to get the relative ancestor wont work. Why not use ContentHacking instead? This way one hacks into the visual tree from the logical elements such as ContextMenu, Popups, ToolTip etc...

1. Declare a StaticResource which is any FrameworkElement (we need support for data context).

   ```
   <UserControl.Resources ...>
           <TextBlock x:Key="ProxyElement" DataContext="{Binding}" />
   </UserControl.Resources>
   ```
2. Supply a content control in the Visual Tree and set this static resource "ProxyElement" as its content.

   ```
   <UserControl ...>
           <Grid ...>
                   <ItemsControl x:Name="MyItemsControl"
                                 ItemsTemplate="{StaticResource blahblah}" .../>
                   <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource ProxyElement}"
                                   DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MyItemsControl}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
   ```

What the above steps have done that "ProxyElement" has been connected to the ItemsControl (which serves as a DataContext) and it is available as a SaticResource to be used anywhere.

1. Now use this StaticResource as a source for any bindings which are failing in your tooltip...

   ```
   <Grid ...>
           <TextBlock x:Name="ObjectText"
                      ToolTipService.Placement="Left"
                      ToolTip="{StaticResource ItemToolTip}"
                      PlacementTarget="{Binding Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}, Path=DataContext}" ... /> <!-- This sets the target as the items control -->
   ```

and

```
    <ToolTip x:Key="ItemToolTip">
            <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}, Path=DataContext.DataContext}"><!-- sets data context of the items control -->
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName.Name}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Details}" FontStyle="Italic"/> ...
            </StackPanel>
    </ToolTip>
```

Let me know if this helps...

Comment: This is interesting, and I played around with it for a while but couldn't get it to work on the actual items within the listbox. I don't think the issue is the visual tree not being available. With the code in the sample question, the error I get from the binding engine is that it's trying to bind to the listbox's vm, instead of the item's vm. If the tooltip not being part of the visual tree was the problem, then I would expect the error to be about trying to bind to null or perhaps the main window's vm. But it's successfully found the listbox's vm. What I want is to make it use the item's vm.

Comment: Another thing I tried was to put the ContentControl with Content set to the proxy static resource inside of the item DataTemplate. That bound successfully but would not rebind as I hovered tooltips over each of the data items (it stayed bound to the first).

Comment: So Scott, are you trying to say that DisplayName.Name and Details are properties of individual item or of the listbox's vm?

Comment: They're properties of the individual item. But is ok, I got an answer I'm happy with and posted it. Check it out, do you like?

Comment: Thx Scott for the Bounty! :-)

Comment: It would have gone to waste and I liked the effort in your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand [but I probably wrong (no harm in trying)], you can initialize your items with reference to objects which were used in ancestor DataContext, i.e.

```
public class ItemsVM<T> : VMBase
{
     public T parentElement;
     public ItemsVM (T _parentElement)
     {
         this.parentElement = _parentElement;
     }

     ...

}
```

Comment: My VM tree does have parent references to the owner. The problem is that I have the reverse issue - it is getting bound to the listbox's vm and what I need is data in the item vm.